# Why are the download files missing on PyPI's website?

Tags: python, pypi

The PyPI webpage for `PyVimeo` only contains some basic information, it does not contain a list of files that can be downloaded.

Here's the URL: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyVimeo

[image: Screenshot]

I was expecting a table of download files. For instance, this is what Django's PyPI page looks like:

[image: Screenshot]

You can see that you can download `.tar.gz` and `.whl` files.

What's odd is that `pip install PyVimeo` works, even though it doesn't seem to have any downloadable files.

Answer (score 2):

Odd.  Although there are no files listed for version 0.3.9 (the latest) of PyVimeo, [the page for the previous version (0.3.8)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyVimeo/0.3.8) lists one file, which is for version 0.3.9!  I don't know whether this is due to a mistake on PyPI's part or PyVimeo's, but installation with `pip` continues to work because it checks https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyvimeo/, which lists all PyVimeo files, including the 0.3.9 tarball that PyPI otherwise thinks is for 0.3.8.

Answer (score 2):

There could be a few different reasons why an entry on PyPI does not have any files listed.

Years ago, files were not listed on PyPI. Instead, the files would be hosted by the project maintainer at the website listed under "Home Page". Due to some obvious impracticalities which that system, support was later added to list and host the files directly on PyPI. However, you can still find some old packages which have not been updated in recent years and  still do not host their files on PyPI.

Of course, pyvimeo is not such a package. However, that explains why it is possible to have a listing for a version with no files. In fact, creating a new version for a package on PyPI and uploading the files for that version are two separate steps. It's possible that the project maintainer simply forgot to complete step two. Or perhaps there is a bug in their automation script which they use to update to the newest version. Given the observations made in other answers (that every version seems to be off by one), the later seems to be the most likely cause to me.

Other answers have also suggested that it could be a problem with PyPI. While that's true, we can only be sure after eliminating the possibility that there was no error by the package maintainer. I would suggest [reporting](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.py/issues/new) the problem to the packager maintainer directly. In fact, reviewing their [closed issues](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.py/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed), I see a number of issues where users are having trouble installing the latest version. However, in the few I read, no one seemed to notice that the file versions don't match the listed version on PyPI.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a hiccup with the PyPi-Index. The simple index correctly lists PyVimeo 0.3.9: https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyvimeo/
The error seems to go back to [0.3.3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyVimeo/0.3.3); while [0.3.2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyVimeo/0.3.2) links to 0.3.2, 0.3.3 links to both archives for 0.3.3 and 0.3.4. After that, every version is one off, so (with 0.3.5 missing) [0.3.4](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyVimeo/0.3.4) links to 0.3.6 and so on.
So for some reason version 0.3.9 seems to be looking for the files for version 0.4.0 which don't exist. Hence no download link.